# Is it safe to access an array value in the stop condition of the loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, standards, conditional-statements

To improve performance in my clique-partitioning program, which uses ordered arrays, I included in the stop condition of my `for` loop an access to an element of the array I'm looping into.

```
int myValue = 13;

for (int i=0; array[i] < myValue; i++)
{
    //performing operations on the array
}
```

This is clearly unsafe, since it could be that my array only contains values that are less than `myValue`, so I tried this

```
int myValue = 13;

for (int i=0; i < array.size() && array[i] < myValue; i++)
{
    //performing operations on the array
}
```

In this implementation, all seems to go well, but if I switch the conditions, I fall into the same problem of the first example.

```
int myValue = 13;

for (int i=0; array[i] < myValue && i < array.size(); i++)
{
    //performing operations on the array
}
```

So, I deduced that this is clearly due to the way the compiler sets the order of the two conditions, since in the last case, even if I ask to enter the loop only if `i` is not greater than the size of the array, I'm previously reading a value that could be out of the bounds of the array.

My question is: is it always safe to do as I did in the second implementation, or could the compiler sometimes switch my control conditions leading to unsafe code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `&&` (logical and) operator *always* short circuits if it can. Your second example is safe.

Note, this applies to primitive types only, not those that overload the boolean operators.

Because no self-respecting `C++` answer would be complete without a [standard quote](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf):

> **5.14.1 (Logical AND)**
>   The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to type bool (Clause 4).
>   The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the ﬁrst operand is false.
>
> **5.14.2 (Logical OR)**
>   The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It
>   returns true if either of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, || guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not evaluated if the ﬁrst operand evaluates to true.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer, this also taught me a lot on how stackoverflow works (it was my first question here)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do either examples. Do this:

```
for (int i=0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    if (array[i] >= myValue) {
        break;
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

This way you don't have any confusion or lack of safety. It has the same speed as the other examples but it's far more straightforward for debugging later.

Comment: While I agree this is better code, it doesn't really answer the question. The gist of his question is actually unrelated to looping, but about how `&&` works.

Comment: I think this answer does concern with my question, too. In fact I thought about a solution like this but I didn't realize it was so simple (and also I normally avoid `break`s because I was taught so)

Comment: `break` is dangerous for very beginning programmers because it can result in code that does 'unexpected' things. But it makes looping logic much, much more straightforward once you're out of your second week of CS 001. I do think it's important to understand early exits and logical operators but code readability is extremely important too. "Loop through every element in the array. IF the element is too big, stop looping." versus "loop when the elements are small, but stop when they're too big and when the array is done". Which English is less confusing? Therefore which code is less confusing?